# IModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' in VS Code editor while no problem with terminal

Tags: django, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm new to django, and want to use it in VS Code. However, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'" blocked me.

I've pip installed virtual environment, it worked fine in terminal.

on terminal, it shows:

```
(myenv) Kates-MacBook:~ kate.wang$ python3
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 03:13:28)
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> from django.shortcuts import render
>>>
```

on VS Code, it outputs:

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/kate.wang/myenv/my_django_project/blog/views.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/kate.wang/myenv/my_django_project/blog/views.py", line 1, in <module>
from django.shortcuts import render
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

My VS Code Settings are:

```
{
"workbench.iconTheme": "vs-minimal",
"editor.fontSize": 15,
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
"terminal.integrated.fontSize": 14,
"workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
"workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
"python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
"workbench.sideBar.location": "left",
"workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
"kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
"python.pythonPath": "python3.7",
"python.venvPath": "/Users/kate.wang/myenv"
```

}

This problem has bothered me for days since I've been trying different solutions from stackoverflow and other websites the first time it poped up and didn't find a way to solve it.

Thank you for your time to help me.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by installing the django using pip3.
just run this command **pip3 install django** in virtual environment of workspace folder.

Answer (score 2):

Had a the same problem.

1. you have to make sure your python extension is using the current activated virtual environment.

This is the solution :

1. To select a specific environment, use the Python: Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette `Ctrl+Shift+p`

[a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wah5U.png)

Selecting an interpreter from the list adds an entry for `python.pythonPath`

for more details.  [Read this documentation-](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#:%7E:text=To%20do%20so%2C%20open%20the,Settings%2C%20with%20the%20appropriate%20interpreter.)

Please let me know whether it worked

Comment: This works for me.
I have different versions of Python in my local machine, and by choosing the correct version of Python in Vscode helps me to do Run and Debug :)

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered with the same problem.
Solution is -
Please choose the latest python interpreter, ----- press ctrl + p and then type >Python: Select Interpreter (don't forget the > character! if it doesn't show up, make sure you have installed python extension on your vs code).------ It will show you available interpreters (virtual environments + the global environment) to choose.
Please don't go for virtual environment or pip installation if you're very new to django
please see the link (snap) below for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to the top menu bar of the visual studio code
Click on view
then command palette
after select interpreter
choose virtualenvWrapper

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your virtual environment's python in **`python.pythonPath`**. You need to change it to:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/Users/kate.wang/myenv/bin/python",
```

Comment: Still the same problem after changing to the above pythonPath setting

Comment: can you please make sure your [ms python server](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server) or jade for python in vscode(whichever setup you are using) is working properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python's `VENV` (Virtual environment), activate your `venv` (Django must be installed on this `venv`) from terminal and after `venv` is active in terminal,,, just type `code .` (in terminal). I think, this is exactly what you need.

Comment: (myenv) Kates-MacBook:~ kate.wang$ python3 shows it's already activated.  however, (myenv) Kates-MacBook:~ kate.wang$ code .
-bash: code: command not found

Comment: When your venv is activated (myenv) type python in terminal and try to import django from terminal. import django... what it gives you as a result ?

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed it using pip3 and so it gives no error when you use the terminal. Check if you have multiple versions.

Answer (score 0):

You might change the python interpreter in vs code editor (in the lower-left corner) it should be working.